# Assigning value to class method with parameters in C#

Tags: c#, com, vbscript, .net-assembly, backwards-compatibility

I'm working in an assembly in C# that will replace an old DLL registered as COM. That old DLL allowed COM enabled applications (like VB or Perl) or do things like in the following VBS example:

```
dim All_Domains
set All_Domains = WScript.CreateObject("MailServerX.LocalDomains")

dim Specific_Domain
set Specific_Domain = All_Domains.Items(3)

dim Domain_Aliases
set Domain_Aliases = WScript.CreateObject("MailServerX.Lines")
Domain_Aliases.Add "one.com"
Domain_Aliases.Add "two.com"

Specific_Domain.Domain_Aliases = Domain_Aliases
All_Domains.Items(3) = Specific_Domain
```

As you can see in the last line, the property/method LocalDomains.Items is being assigned while passing the parameter "3".

I need to maintain the same interface in the new assembly in order to keep compatibility with all existing scripts that access the old DLL. I have this (very summarized) C# class:

```
public class LocalDomains
{
    private List<LocalDomain> itemsList = new List<LocalDomain>();
    # Assume the list is now loaded
    public LocalDomain Items(int index)
    {
        return itemsList[index];
    }
}
```

How can I write the method Items in the class LocalDomains so it can not only return a value from the list, but also receive a value assignment so it can do some processing with itemsList[index] including assigning the new value to it?

By that I mean, keeping the last line of my first code block valid with the new code.

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: Are you looking for something like [Indexed Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/aa288464(v=vs.71).aspx)?

Comment: Not exactly, or maybe I'm not processing the idea very well in my head. What I need is to be able to keep using a script like the one in my first block, and I'm not sure how to write that in C# yet.

Comment: Beg, steal or borrow to get the type library for the old DLL.  Import it into your project and implement the interfaces.